# Table saved only while running

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I'm new at working with Entity Framework and used Model First approach. I then tried to create a table but when the program closes it's gone.

My code:

```
using (var objCtx = new EntityModelContainer())
                {
                    //Inserting Student using ExecuteStoreCommand
                    string command = "CREATE TABLE clients (Id INTEGER, Name nvarchar(4000))";
                    int InsertedRows = objCtx.ExecuteStoreCommand(command);
                }
```

How can I save tables permanently?

Comment: don't you need to do `objCtx.SaveChanges()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add `objCtx.SaveChanges();` before `ojbCtx` got disposed.

Answer (score 1):

its because you are using "using" means you are disposing it. Try below if you don't want to dispose it.

```
var objCtx = new EntityModelContainer()
                {
                    //Inserting Student using ExecuteStoreCommand
                    string command = "CREATE TABLE clients (Id INTEGER, Name nvarchar(4000))";
                    int InsertedRows = objCtx.ExecuteStoreCommand(command);
                    objCtx.SaveChanges();
                }
```

For more information :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6564/Understanding-the-using-statement-in-C

And as mentioned in above document

> The using statement is only useful for objects with a lifetime that
>   does not extend beyond the method in which the objects are
>   constructed. Remember that the objects you instantiate must implement
>   the System.IDisposable interface.
>
> There is no equivalent for the using statement in vb.net. You have to
>   use the try finally block.

And you will need to add `objCtx.SaveChanges();`  in your code.

Comment: if the object gets disposed shouldn't the data still be stored in the db regardless?